# Finding unique values in hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I have a hive table **table_perm** which has a million rows. Everyday new data is appended into this table from another hive table, **table_temp**.

Let's say the tables are as below:

**table_perm**

`id,col2,col3,ts
1,a,b,t1
2,d,e,t1
3,g,h,t1
4,j,k,t2
5,a,e,t2
6,h,d,t2`

**table_temp**

`id,col2,col3,ts
6,h,k,t3
7,d,r,t3
8,a,h,t3
9,t,q,t3`

and my final output should be,

`id,col2,col3,ts
1,a,b,t1
2,d,e,t1
3,g,h,t1
4,j,k,t2
5,a,e,t2
6,h,k,t3
7,d,r,t3
8,a,h,t3
9,t,q,t3`

so basically I have to validate here if the id is unique and then append the data. In case the id is not unique, append the latest record.

What should be my approach to find the unique id value and insert in table_perm considering the table_perm is huge, validating each value of the column `id` could be tedious.

**P.S. :** column ts is timestamp and incremental update happens once every day.
table_perm is huge.

Comment: What is your question? Is the data being appended correctly?

Comment: @GordonLinoff : updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Way to Do it is
Do a  table_perm join table_temp  on id.
Then select fields accordingly by checking ts.

```
select table_perm.id,IF(table_perm.ts>table_temp.ts,table_perm.col2,table_temp.col2), IF(table_perm.ts>table_temp.ts,table_perm.col3,table_temp.col3)
from table_perm join table_perm on table_perm.id=table_perm.id
```

> Donn't Worry about the Size of Data.Hive is For Big Data Applications

Comment: This makes the whole process real slow... Say I have 15 columns, checking all the columns would take lot of time.

Comment: Is Your Application is doing real time processing?If so using hive is not a valid tool for your usecase. If it is not a realtime donn't worry about data and time

Comment: No we are not doing real time processing. But this data goes into presentation tables and we do analytics on top of SAS VA. We are targeting the whole process to take less than 10 mins.

Comment: Are You Using Spark Cluster with Hive or Hadoop cluster with Hive. If you want to bring it to less than 10 minutes, I guess spark with hive does it.